# "String was not recognized as valid Datetime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0" while reading CSV file back

Tags: c#, datetime, tostring

so I'm using CSVhelper to read and write CSV files. I have made a class with the following properties to be written into the file.

```
public class Proddeets {
public string ProductArea { get; set; }
public string Product { get; set; }
public DateTime TimeTaken{ get; set; }
}
```

When I'm trying to read back the file I get the "String was not recognized as valid Datetime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0" error

I've tried fixing it by creating a function for the TimeTaken prop

```
public void SetTimeTaken()
{DateTime today= DateTime.Today;
String s = today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
TimeTaken=s.Trim();
}
```

I get the 'cannot implicitly convert DateTime to string' error. I'm new to C# and I'm not sure how to go about this, please help

Comment: The shown code won’t generate that compilation error. Ensure to include the *exact* compiler error. (In any case, `TimeTaken = "string;"` is an error, as TimeTaken is a DateTime, not a string.)

Comment: Please include a sample of the CSV file where the error occurs.

Comment: The CSV file simply contains the column names as given in the class properties of Proddeets i.e ProductArea, product and TimeTaken

Comment: Show us the first 3 lines of the CSV as well as how you’re reading it

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to set the value of a datetime with function that returns a string, try using `TimeTaken=Convert.ToDateTime(s);` instead

And use `string` instead of `String` as a good practice.

Comment: I have tried what you said but it's the same error as before

Comment: *I have tried what you said and while the 'cannot implicitly convert DateTime to string' error goes away, 'the unknown word at index 0'  error is still there